# Sluggish NAS Performance with AFP

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, nas, finder

Just got my self a NAS (Asustor AS1002T) to handle my files. It is supposed to be up to 110MB/s read and 90MB/s write, it has two Seagate 2TB Barracuda running in RAID 1.

**The Setup**

I have a Archer C7 router connected to my ISP modem (internet in port), and then the NAS connected to the Archer C7, which has a gigabit connection. I access the server via WiFi with my iMac running High Sierra. All wired connections are Cat5e.

**The problem**

Sluggish performance. It takes more than 1 minute for a 100 MB transfer. More than transfer times, Finder is really slow showing files - in a tree-like structure, it takes a few moments to load the contents inside the tree. Deleting a 10kb Python file from the NAS takes about 10-15 seconds, and it looks like it does not understand the process in question (does not say how many files are being deleted, nor the estimated time remaining).

Navigating with the File Explorer of the NAS, running within the web browser is a lot faster than navigating with Finder. When using a wired connection transfer times seems fine, but I still get that slugginess when navigating with Finder. Inserting data to a NAS-hosted DataBase (MySQL) is ridiculously slow (15 inserts/second), simple SELECT queries take about 5 seconds to run.

Blackmagic Disk Test says wired connections are running at 60MB/s write and 100MB/s read, and wireless connections are running at 45MB/s for both write and read speeds, but it sure doesn't feel that way when working with the unit.

Ping seems ok: no loss packages, with 1.4 ms avg time. My internet connection seems ok: still getting the speed delivered by my ISP provider with no problems.

I'm running AFP, with everything disabled (SMB, FTP, WebDAV, etc). Any ideas what can I do to troubleshoot and fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What performance do you get from SMB for comparison? Apple's recommendation is to use SMBv3 instead of AFP.

Comment: Roughly the same, changed to AFP after reading a few posts saying they got better performance with it.  SMBv3 is still smb:// ipaddress?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this post from 4 years ago but going through similar challenges. Wondering if the original post author ever solved the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please note that SE sites are not discussion forums - "Answers" are strictly for providing answers, not for "me-too" -type postings. If you have an issue, you should post a separate question. You can refer to this one if it contains info that's relevant to your situation as well. Please see https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask for instructions on how to formulate a good question - in general checking the Help is a very good idea in every SE community. This kind of postings get deleted, which will affect your reputation, which again affects what you can do here. So I'

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170945)